# Missing file in java.library.path

Tags: java, netbeans, classpath, openni

While compiling a demo from openni i stumbled across this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no OpenNI.jni in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1758)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1045)
at org.OpenNI.NativeMethods.<clinit>(NativeMethods.java:34)
at org.OpenNI.Context.initFromXmlEx(Context.java:317)
at org.OpenNI.Context.createFromXmlFile(Context.java:36)
at kitouch.UserTracker.<init>(UserTracker.java:113)
at kitouch.UserTrackerApplication.main(UserTrackerApplication.java:46)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 4 seconds)
```

I'm doing this on my mac . And my best guess is that this file `libOpenNI.jni.dylib` is not in my java.library.path

My question now is: Is this guess right, and how do i add `libOpenNI.jni.dylib` to my java.library.path in netbeans.

Thx in advance

Comment: Nvm found it ... i really should learn to browse the interwebs longer. The answer is : add this to VM option of the projects property: -Djava.library.path=/Users/olivierjanssens/Development/Kinect/OpenNI/Lib/

this is where the dylib file is

Comment: If you've found the solution, please add it as an answer.

Comment: It might also just work if that file were in the project's base directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add this to VM option of the projects
 property: -Djava.library.path=/Users/olivierjanssens/Development/Kinect/OpenNI/Lib/

this is where the dylib file

Comment: Also make sure that you're using a JVM with the corresponding architecture. That is, if you're using OpenNI x64 you should also use a 64 bit java version.

Comment: Its working now. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714785/giving-java-library-path-in-netbeans-for-dll-so-files/11898261#11898261