# Is there a netbeans equivalent to "Native library location" in eclipse for jar files?

Tags: java, netbeans, configuration, buildpath, java.library.path

In eclipse you can add a native library location for each jar file in your project.  I prefer this method to adding a `-Djava.library.path` to the VM arguments.  Is there an equivalent in netbeans or am I stuck with the `-D`?

This is related to this question:
[How to set the java.library.path from Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957700/how-to-set-the-java-library-path-from-eclipse)

Comment: There is a same type of question already asked here. [Missing file in java.library.path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8361728/missing-file-in-java-library-path)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell from everything I've read and tried, you must use `-Djava.library.path` in netbeans.

Answer (score -2):

[project] - right click - Properties - Libraries - Compile - Add JAR/Folder - [yourjar.jar] (+ "Absolute Path" on the right side of the dialog)

Comment: It's not a jar I'm trying to add, it's a Native Library - a DLL.

Comment: No.  It definitely wouldn't work under "Compile" because java.library.path is used at runtime.  However, I tried putting it there (for giggles) and in "Run" and it still didn't work.  My guess is that it's because these lists are merely adding jar files and folders to you classpath, not to java.library.path.  One is for java libraries, one is for native libraries.