# giving 'java.library.path' in netbeans for .dll/.so files

Tags: java, netbeans, library-path

How do i give the path for the `.dll` or `.so` file in netbeans to load the library using

```
System.loadLibrary("Foo")
```

I read [this on netbeans page but couldn't help me.](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-openide-modules/org/openide/modules/doc-files/api.html#jni) as it gives the unsatisfied link error.

These are the two things i tried :

In the following snapshot i created a `lib` folder inside the netbeans project and placed the `dll` files inside it.

[image]

In the second snapshot i created a `lib` folder inside the `modules` folder and placed all the `dll` files inside `lib` folder as stated in the [link](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-openide-modules/org/openide/modules/doc-files/api.html#jni).

[image]

But both of them give me `unsatisfied link error` exception. How do i set `java.library.path` in netbeans so that i can directly test the application from netbeans,
without having to go and write on the terminal ?

Comment: That only works for applications using the NetBeans platform, not for normal Java SE applications. Answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8361728/missing-file-in-java-library-path

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Its working now. Some little bit setting you have to do with your Netbean IDE.Only of Netbean IDE.

**Follow the Steps :-**

```
==>Right click on the Project
==>Properties
==>Click on RUN
==>VM Options : -Djava.library.path="C:\Your Directory where Dll is present"
==>Ok
```

Its working 100%. I have done this in my own project.

Comment: How can you do this with 2 diffrent library paths? Say one in my desktop file and another in my program files, file?

Comment: Thanks, I found it works -Djava.library.path="path1";"path2" as well. Just a note to everyone who is reading this, Dont do what i did and enter the dll's name into the file path.

Comment: @JDeveloper : hello I am working in Ubuntu OS then how can be .dll workS?

Comment: @JavaMan ,I think .dll will not work on ubuntu or any unix flavour OS.You can configure the path using Build Path.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Netbeans is still trying to look in the old location for the dll. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: in *netbeans 8.2* for  some reason it won't work without adding the word `java` in the beginning : `java -Djava.library.path="C:\Your Directory where Dll is present"`

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Mac OS X Yosemite and Netbeans 8.02, I got the same error and the simple solution I have found is like above, this is useful when you need to include native library in the project. So do the next for Netbeans:

```
1.- Right click on the Project
2.- Properties
3.- Click on RUN
4.- VM Options: java -Djava.library.path="your_path"
5.- for example in my case: java -Djava.library.path=</Users/Lexynux/NetBeansProjects/NAO/libs>
6.- Ok
```

I hope it could be useful for someone.
The link where I found the solution is here:
[java.library.path – What is it and how to use](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/java-library-path-what-is-it-and-how-to-use/)

Answer (score 1):

To me JDeveloper's suggestion didn't work. However, the method that I came across this early afternoon works handy.
It is for netbeans 8.02, and Visual Studio 2013 generated dll.

1. create a package(eg, "dll") under [Source Packages] node of netbeans
   project
2. put/copy a dll file(eg, simpleDLL.dll) into the package(eg,
   "dll")
3. on the [Libraries] node of the netbeans project, right-click
   and choose "Add Jar/Folder...",
4. navigate to the folder("src") that contains the folder("dll") for the package that you created in step 1 above (it could be "...\src\dll" in my example), select package folder("dll") and click [Open] button to select it.

-- now you should have added a folder("dll") (which contains the dll file{simpleDLL.dll}) to the Libraries node of the project.

That's it. It should work!
Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

IF you are working on "NetBeans Modules"

DLLs or SOs can be placed in the folder release/modules/lib/ in a module project's sources (look in the Files tab). This will make them appear in the final NBM or application in a lib subdirectory beneath where the module's JAR resides. Then just use System.loadLibrary as usual.