# Error when trying to compile a Java program with a Jar generated by the Matlab JA compiler

Tags: matlab, netbeans, matlab-compiler, javabuilders

I've generated the .jar based on my Matlab code and added it to my Java project in Netbeans. I have Matlab 2013a and the MCR is correctly installed. The message I get is:

*Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Failed to find the library mclmcrrt8_1.dll, required by MATLAB Builder JA, on java.library.path.
 This library is typically installed along with MATLAB or the MCR, its absence may indicate an issue with that installation or the current path configuration.
The MCR version that this component is trying to use is: 8.1.*

But the file mclmcrrt8_1.dll exists in:
*C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\runtime\win64*

Also, the command *mcrversion* in Matlab gives me an 8.

What should I do? What's wrong?

Comment: try adding the directory `C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\runtime\win64` to the system PATH environment variable

Comment: I already did that but it keeps showing.

Comment: try the following for NetBeans IDE: [giving 'java.library.path' in netbeans for .dll/.so files](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11898261/97160)