# Extracting Text From JPG

Tags: java, image, text, apache-poi, extract

I've tried this code and added the needed jar files but still I'm getting an error message like Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'libtesseract302'.

Is there a complete tutorial how to extract text and what things should be done to address the error? Any help is appreciated...

```
import net.sourceforge.tess4j.*;
import java.io.File;

public class ExtractTxtFromImg {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File imgFile = new File("C:\\Documents and Settings\\rueca\\Desktop\\sampleImg.jpg");
        Tesseract instance = Tesseract.getInstance();  // JNA Interface Mapping
        // Tesseract1 instance = new Tesseract1(); // JNA Direct Mapping

        try {
            String result = instance.doOCR(imgFile);
            System.out.println(result);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In addition to adding the jars, you also need to add the natives. You can do so with `Djava.library.path="C:\[absolute path to dir containing *.dll files and such]"`

Comment: I did it by following the steps from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714785/giving-java-library-path-in-netbeans-for-dll-so-files). but still there is the error. I typed on VM Options -Djava.library.path="C:\Documents and Settings\rueca\Desktop\libtesseract302.dll". Is there something wrong?

Comment: Just `"C:\Documents and Settings\rueca\Desktop\"` is enough. You need to add the directory, not the files.

Comment: :/ no idea then... Are you sure you have all the right natives and that they're in the proper folder?

Comment: Yes. The exact file location is in **C:\Documents and Settings\rueca\Desktop\pet\thesis\resume evaluator\plugins\Tess4J**, and I typed **-Djava.path.library="C:\Documents and Settings\rueca\Desktop\pet\thesis\resume evaluator\plugins\Tess4J\"** on VM Options. Now I'm trying this [one](http://sourceforge.net/p/tess4j/discussion/1202294/thread/370d1e1e/).

Comment: I don't understand this one **I have move the dll and the testdata to the top of the projectstructure (working directory of the project)**

Comment: If this didn't help you I don't know, sorry. :/

Answer (score 1):

In addition to adding the jars, you also need to add the natives. You can do so with `Djava.library.path="C:\[absolute path to dir containing *.dll files and such]"`

Note that you need to provide the directory, not the file itself.