# no lwjgl64 in java.library.path in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

First I couldn't even run my application because of this error.

After downloading the dependencies again and setting the path to the natives folder I was able to run my application without the lwjgl error.

Now when I want to run unit tests I am still receiving this error:

```
no lwjgl64 in java.library.path
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError
....
```

[image]

I don't understand why i get this error while I am able to run the application without getting this error.

Comment: This error means that the native library named `lwjgl64` cannot be found. If this is on Windows then the JVM expects that the system property `java.library.path` is set to a directory that contains `lwjgl64.dll`. You have to set up the run configuration so that this is configured correctly. Search the [LWJGL forums](http://forum.lwjgl.org/) because you're not the first one who encounters this error.

Comment: See also: [giving 'java.library.path' in netbeans for .dll/.so files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714785/giving-java-library-path-in-netbeans-for-dll-so-files?rq=1)

Comment: I have already done this, this fixed the error when i run the application. But I still receive this error when I run a unit test file.

Comment: Then the run configuration for running the unit test is missing the right `java.library.path` setting.